# Text Search in Mysql Table Row and Delete/Update if Exists related to command

Tags: php, mysql, exists

I have some columns in my MySQL table and some descriptions in it,

```
id / name / descriptions
1  / John / a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20
2  / Sam  / a1b01,Value2,2,3,50|b203c,Value 2,0,0,45
3  / Nick / a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50
...
```

as you can see for different people, some variables are same **Value 1**, **Value2** (can include space)/ **a1b01**, **b203c** etc. because, count of descriptions can vary I can't separate them.

I need two MySQL commands that will;

- search for two variables (eg : "a1b01", "Value 1", these'll be taken from a function )
- if both values found in related part then function will delete/update record

I think I should use a function like that

```
function do_action (command,code,desc,new1,new2,newresult) {
if (command == "delete") {
    // First SQL command to delete the founded part
    // but the ramains part should be kept
    // so final result would be : a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20 (for John)
  } elseif (command == "update"){
    // Second SQL command that update the founded part
    // Update founded part
    // so final result would be : a1b01,Value 1,new1,new2,newresult|a1b01,Value2,1,1,50|b203c,Value 1,0,2,20 (for John)
  }
}
```

but I have no idea which MySQL commands should I use?
All your solution, advice or improvement are welcome.

**EDIT :** Used Language is PHP, I am sending data from a php page (index.php) via Jquery's post method, then a php file (data.php) gets these parameters and executes on MySQL database.
Actually may be there is no way other than PHP driven solution, but simply I asked for a php+MySQL function that;
Function takes some parameters and searches for if second+third parameters (code,desc) are exist together in any description row in table (searching), then let function update this part (replace with new ones) or delete record up to first parameter (`command -> delete/update`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the problem into several steps:

- **Determine how you can access the database.** (You don't give any indication of what language you are using and you don't seem to know yet how to access the database.)
- **Figure out if it is possible to employ a better, [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data structure.**
- **If it is, your task is a piece of cake.**
- If not, you have to first read the `values` field from the entry you want to update and find the part you want to be replaced using your procedural language. (There is no regex replace in MySQL.)
- Then assemble a new values string using not SQL but your procedural language.
- If you don't want that for whatever reason (you asked for a MySQL command), you can use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to update the value: `UPDATE the_table SET values = REPLACE(values, "a1b01,Value 1,2,1,60", "Value 1,new1,new2,newresult"`

Comment: I'am using php and there are several function in the project, all use same connection parameters so i have no problem about connecting to db. I'am sory for misinformation i am using PHP (MySQL InnoDB Structure). I've never used normalization before (actually i don't know SQL enough, this is because why i asked that question), let me check it. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Yes, your answer gave me a way to do it. Thanks.